# ArangoDB - Help diagnosing database corruption after system restart

Tags: arangodb

I've been working with Arango for a few months now within a local, single-node development environment that regularly gets restarted for maintenance reasons. About 5 or 6 times now my development database has become corrupted after a controlled restart of my system. When it occurs, the corruption is subtle in that the Arango daemon seems to start ok and the database structurally appears as expected through the web interface (collections, documents are there). The problems have included the Foxx microservice system failing to upload my validated service code (generic 500 service error) as well as queries using filters not returning expected results (damaged indexes?). When this happens, the only way I've been able to recover is by deleting the database and rebuilding it.

I'm looking for advice on how to debug this issue - such as what to look for in log files, server configuration options that may apply, etc. I've read most of the development documentation, but only skimmed over the deployment docs, so perhaps there's an obvious setting I'm missing somewhere to adjust reliability/resilience? (this is a single-node local instance).

Thanks for any help/advice!

Comment: What version are you running on what OS? Is this a self-builld version or a published package?

Comment: Also please share with us, which storage engine you are using.

Comment: Good points - Arango version 3.2.0 (binary dist), running mmfiles storage engine, on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Really 3.2.0? There have been 11 updates to the database software version 3.2. Please consider upgrading to 3.2.11. If the problem persists, I am too happy to help debugging your problem.

Comment: I can do that, but am I correctly inferring from your response that you feel this is an ArangoDB defect rather than a configuration mistake on my part?

Comment: The only thing I could think of would be collections without waitForSync and `kill -9`. Sure then that would be user error. But apart from that this should never happen using a database.

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: It hasn't happened again yet, but I'm also not sure how to reproduce the problem (aside from just restarting regularly). I'll need to test for a week or so before I feel it's fixed. Thanks for the help, btw!

Comment: Still, the updates have fixed a long list of smaller and bigger bugs. Operating an outdated version of ArangoDB is highly unfavourable to put it mildly.

Answer (score 0):

please note that issues like this should rather be discussed on github.